# ' at line 1 MYSQL error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to run a MYSQL script that starts as such:

```
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblStadiumType]    Script Date: 06/24/2010 10:09:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblStadiumType](
    [stadiumtype_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [stadiumtype] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [aaaaatblStadiumType_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
```

I run it in bash using:

```
mysql db_name < script.sql -p
```

However, upon running, I get this error:

```
' at line 1
```

And that's it! I am thoroughly confused, and SQL scripting isn't my strong point, and I'm trying to evaluate a script to understand it to implement it into a PHP script. (The SQL script was sent to me by another developer). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The script is SQL Server. Converting the `CREATE TABLE` script to work on `MySQL` should be straightforward and so will bog standard `CRUD` statements. Is there much else to the script than that?

Comment: There are 5800 lines of code. I need to be able to call the script from a PHP document. Working on a Linux environment....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql doesn't have 'GO'. Instead it uses the ';' deleter.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

etc etc....

Comment: Ooh, good eyes.  That also explains the [bracket].[syntax] around the table identifiers -- that's a MSSQL/Sybase-ism.  ANSI_NULLS is, also.  Conclusion: **This is a different SQL dialect that MySQL won't be able to successfully import without some huge changes.**

Answer (score 2):

Your final parenthesis seems to be the wrong way... See if this makes it any better:

```
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblStadiumType]    Script Date: 06/24/2010 10:09:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblStadiumType](
    [stadiumtype_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [stadiumtype] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [aaaaatblStadiumType_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
)
```

Comment: This is just the beginning of the script... Cut off somewhere half way through a statement. Thanks, though...

Comment: @Kyle Macey: I would highly recommend including *coimplete* code samples whenever you ask a question. Or as a very minimum, *clearly specify* it it's only a small snippet. It not it is much harder to "guess" what your problem might be.

Comment: "I am trying to run a MYSQL script that starts as such:" I thought it was clear enough, I guess not... It was better than pasting the 5800 lines of code :-D